# Execute Stored Procedure Minimal API .Net

Tags: sql, api

Just started playing around with API's and trying to work out how to run a Stored Procedure. I have added this method below to my Minimal API. As far as I can tell the Stored Procedure runs but returns the first line of data over and over.

```
app.MapGet("/AllProducts/{LocationID}", (DataContext context, int LocationID) => context.AllLocationProducts.FromSqlRaw($"GetProducts @LocationNumber='{LocationID}'").ToListAsync());
```

[image: Swagger Result]

Here is the result if I run in SQL.
[image: SQL Result]

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried different sql method but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out the issue, my Model for the Stored Procedure wasn't correct.